# Is it possible for wizards to live solely in the wizarding world, or is it just a temporary place to be?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles, wizards

Wizards can live in the Muggle world, but can they also live in the wizarding world and not have to go to the Muggle world at all? Is it possible for a wizard to be born and raised in the wizarding world, without ever going into the Muggle world?

Comment: https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Hogsmeade - I'd assume that residents of Hogsmeade could have a child, have that child be home-schooled and then go to Hogwarts, leave and get a job in Hogsmeade and never leave again. Possible yes. Likely, no

Comment: It's not a *place*.

Answer (score 4):

Since the Wizarding World refers to a culture or way of life more than a place, I would imagine it would be difficult, but possible. It would be like a Chinese person moving to America. If they live in a big city, they can stick to portions of town that are mainly Chinese, go only to Chinese groceries and doctors, and do all their state-required paperwork online or with the help of a better-informed family member. If they live in a dedicated rural community that has decided to be Chinese, they would actually have to go into traditional Western society more often, any time they needed something beyond what their local village provides, unless they chose to bend over backwards to avoid it (dedicated trips into the Chinese part of the city and do without the rest of the time, for example).
Alternatively, a Chinese immigrant can just live Chinese in their own house and not worry too much about what the neighbors think, so long as the local religious extremists don't try to burn their house down because they keep an altar for Buddha and/or their ancestors. Most likely, they'd mostly just not mention the altar in our real-world comparison, whereas your wizarding folk would actively hide their wizarding stuff when their muggle neighbors came over because of the Wizarding Secrecy laws.

The problem for wizarding folk is that, unlike our Chinese friend, they don't have a home nation dedicated solely to their use. So, they have to either arrange things so muggle authority literally cannot find them (difficult, but not impossible) or arrange to placate muggle authority by doing the bare minimum to keep state paperwork up to date, and just never have muggles over.

Don't know if that answers your question, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I find "the local religious extremists" to be offensive since it's probably referring to Christians. Please remove that or I'll flag this answer for removal.

Comment: "it's probably referring to Christians", well, that isn't an offensive assumption at all is it /s ... religion seems like a good analogy in the real world to the magic - "person practicing weird rites, etc. - she's a witch!" so seems like a valid comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Although some wizards behave as if they little knowledge of the Muggle world e.g by their bizarre attempts to dress as Muggles or Mr Weasley’s question about rubber ducks. In reality, I would suspect it’s unlikely.

They all have to travel to London to go to Kings Cross, Diagon Alley, MOM etc so in that respect they will literally be in the Muggle world.  Perhaps there will be minimal interaction for some but in reality they will also rely on the Muggle world for food, clothing and other necessities.